# Flatten 2D list with indices

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, flatten

I am looking for an idiomatic method in Kotlin (JVM) to **flatten** a 2-dimensional list. But, unlike the existing `.flatten()`, I would like to **retain the individual indices**, similar to `.withIndex()`, but **2-dimensional**.

Example:

```
// Before
[
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e"],
  ["f", "g", "h", "i"]
]

// Afterwards, something like
[
  (0, 0, "a"), (0, 1, "b"), (0, 2, "c"),
  (1, 0, "d"), (1, 1, "e"),
  (2, 0, "f"), (2, 1, "g"), (2, 2, "h"), (2, 3, "i")
]
```

Comment: Couldnt find anything similar on SO yet, so I decided to share my solution to this problem for everyone, to enrich search results, hence the self-answer.

Comment: At first I misread the question as a Dart question, since I have both Kotlin and Dart as my favorite tags. I made a Dart solution for fun using regular for loops. You can check it here https://pastebin.com/LStEq3Je

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `flattenWithIndex`

Unsure whether there is an idiomatic approach to this already somewhere in the lib, but it is fairly easy to write this yourself with a bunch of nested `.withIndex()` and some (flat)-mapping:

```
// inspired by IndexedValue for 1D
data class GridValue<out T>(val rowIndex: Int, val colIndex: Int, val value: T)

// similar to flatten().withIndex() for 1D
fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>>.flattenWithIndex(): List<GridValue<T>> =
  withIndex().flatMap { (rowIndex, row) ->
    row.withIndex().map { (colIndex, value) ->
      GridValue(rowIndex, colIndex, value)
    }
  }
```

---

#### `withGridIndex`

As a little bonus, here is the 2D variant of `withIndex()`:

```
// only difference is map vs flatMap
fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>>.withGridIndex(): List<List<GridValue<T>>> =
  withIndex().map { (rowIndex, row) ->
    row.withIndex().map { (colIndex, value) ->
      GridValue(rowIndex, colIndex, value)
    }
  }
```

---

#### Notes

As usual, substitute with **sequences** if necessary.

Technically, `flattenWithIndex()` could also be rewritten as

```
fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>>.flattenWithIndex(): List<GridValue<T>> =
  withGridIndex().flatten()
```

But that would create unecessary lists in the process.

Answer (score 1):

As you describe question is actually do type conversion like: `List<List<String>>` to `List<Triple<Int, Int, String>>`

Generalization: `List<List<T>>` to `List<Triple<Int, Int, T>>`
and code is:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<List<T>>.flattenWithIndex(): List<Triple<Int, Int, T>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<Triple<Int, Int, T>>()
    forEachIndexed { i, tList ->
        tList.forEachIndexed { j, t ->
            result.add(Triple(i, j, t))
        }
    }
    return result
}

val list = listOf(listOf("a", "b", "c"), listOf("d", "e"), listOf("f", "g", "h", "i"))
println(list.flattenWithIndex())// [(0, 0, a), (0, 1, b), (0, 2, c), (1, 0, d), (1, 1, e), (2, 0, f), (2, 1, g), (2, 2, h), (2, 3, i)]
```

Comment: I like how you directly add into the target list instead of doing map/flatMap _magic_, but at the same time keep it nice with `forEachIndexed`.